# Determine which Decimal Symbol is used in Customized Format settings of particular system

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, double, decimal-point

How to know which Decimal Symbol `"."`,  `","`, `"'"` is used in Windows System  `Region/Formats/Additional Settings/Customize Format` settings.

In my system, it is a dot `"."`, and if in my code I have this mark for double number insert with textbox to computation, for example part to allow only one decimal point:

```
 if ((e.KeyChar == ',') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf(',') > -1))
```

On my system it works proper, no matters which mark is used in code and which Decimal Symbol is used in Customize Format settings, dot, comma or apostrophe, no matters corresponding to each other or not.

But on the another computer, same program throws me an exception `"input string was not in correct format"`.

Then I checked two versions of program on this system, one with dot `'.'` and another with comma `','` and unlike my system, works only version which symbol corresponds to the Customize Format setting, and I got exception for one or another.

First of all I can't get why on my system it is no matters, which mark is used in setting, and why it is matters on another system.

So I'm not sure if I have to use replace method for this case as this mark comes in action  on the stage of computation in `Math`, before I need to know, which symbol is used in particular system setting to prevent it with correspondent symbol I guess, but I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: You can find what is the character used in _CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator_

Comment: You have to decide on the context of the information. "System" isn't very precise. Likely, you want the UI thread's current culture unless you are going to write numbers formatted as text into a system log.

Comment: @Steve Hello, yes exactly, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to convert a user input to decimal?

You can use [Double.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx) directly to do that.

```
result = Double.TryParse(input, NumberStyles.Any,
          CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat, 
          out number);
```

There is an [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762964(v=vs.110).aspx) covering this.

If you want to parse the input manually, then [CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class has the set of seperators as part of it's property depending on the type of input you are expecting.